# How to modify query parameters inside queryParamsDidChange method in Ember.Route class?

Tags: ember.js

The idea is when the `type` parameter change, I will modify the `page` parameter value to its default value.

I tried `this.queryParams.page = 1` but it doesn't work.
I also tried `this.paramsFor(this.routeName).page = 1` but also it doesn't work.

How can I solve this? Thanks.

> Ember.Route Class:

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Route.extend({

  queryParams: {
    page: {refreshModel: true},
    type: {refreshModel: true}
  },

  model(params) {
    return this.store.query('posts', params);
  },

  actions: {
    queryParamsDidChange(changed, totalPresent, removed) {
      this._super(...arguments);

      if(changed.type) {
        //TODO: Modify the value of page parameter
      }
    }
  }

});
```

---

> Ember.Controller Class:

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Controller.extend({

  queryParams: ['page', 'type'],

  page: 1,
  type: null

});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Query params are bound to controller properties, as shown by your second code block. To change a query param, you have to change the property on the controller:

```
queryParamsDidChange(changed, totalPresent, removed) {
  this._super(...arguments);

  if (changed.type) {
    this.controller.set('page', 1);
  }
}
```

Having said that, if you are changing a query param from inside the `queryParamsDidChange`, you might get into an endless loop of continuously changing the query param, so be careful!

Comment: Note that if you enter this route from a complete refresh (i.e. not following a link in from elsewhere) things may blow up as `setupController` gets called **after** `queryParamsDidChange` and the various model hooks are called ...